# Value added into subform is numerical value and not descriptive value

Tags: ms-access

I have created 2 combo boxes, (one called "Customer Name" the other called "Part Name") where the list in "Part Name" is filtered based on what has been chosen in "Customer Name".

These combo boxes are on a form that adds in new data into a subform (the subform is created based of a table). The problem i have now is that whenever i choose the values in both combo boxes, what is stored in the subform is the ID of the Customer and Part Name.

I would like to have the descriptive value (Actual name) to be stored and displayed.

I tried changing the column widths but it won't work.

[image: Choosing the data]

[image: The ID of the data is displayed, but not the actual name]

Comment: You can either change the bound column of the combo, or better, you can create combos in the subform.

Comment: I tried changing the bound columns of both combo, but what happens now is that the values in the "Part Name" combo doesn't appear @Fionnuala

Comment: Either create comboboxes as @Fionnuala suggests, or modify the query you use as source for the subform to include an outer join to the table holding the description of the value.

Comment: "Or better" wouldn't work because the end user is not suppose to add data through the subform, only through the form with the combos @Fionnuala.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but how do i do that? @Gustav

Comment: Just because the user cannot add data does not mean you cannot have a combo, however, it looks like a query is getting to be your best bet.

Comment: Use the query designer to adjust your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how you are populating the combo's data to the subform.

If you are doing it through VBA, then you could use the `column` property of the combo to pass the descriptive column. Or better yet, the `Text` property using the beforeupdate event.

```
 me.subform1!partname.value = me.ComboBoxpartname.text
```

Comment: Hello @Lybren thank you for your answer! However, i am getting an error " Complie Error, Expected: = " on this line of code " Me.7a_SubForm_Daily_Material.Part_Name.value = me.cboCustomer_Name.text ". How do i work around it?

Comment: My bad, @Hamizan instead of dot use exclamation mark when accessing subform's control.

Comment: @Hamizan, dont forget to mark the answer as correct to have closure.

Comment: Sorry about that! @Lybren I'm very new to this website. Thank you for your help!